# Shift right zero fill operator >>> in Java: porting to C++

Tags: java, c++, porting, logical-operators

I'm doing a java code porting to c++ and I have some logical instructions with shift:

```
 ((byte) ((buffer >>> 8) & 0xFF));
```

**How** can I write the same in C++?

byte, that doesn't exists natively in c++, I've defined as:

```
typedef unsigned char byte;
```

Comment: The C++ type which corresponds to Java's `byte` is `signed char`.  (At least on most typical machines, where `CHAR_BIT == 8`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For unsigned integer types, `>>` will fill with zero bits, just as Java's `>>>` does.

Note: for signed types with a negative value, the result is implementation-defined, so it's probably best to avoid that case, and not rely on it filling with ones as the Java `>>` would.

Comment: I've tried, but I have buffer=258374 (buffer is a const unsigned int).. So  ((byte) ((258374 >>> 8) & 0xFF)); give me: fffffff1 while I'm a expecting f1

Comment: @Velthune: Works for me: http://ideone.com/nJhehi. Your real code probably uses signed types somewhere. If you have a question about the behaviour of some specific code, then please post some code that demonstrates that behaviour.

Comment: @Velthune as `>>>` isn't a valid operator in C++, I'm curious how `((byte) ((258374 >>> 8) & 0xFF));` even *compiles*, much less gives you a result of `0xFFFFFFF1`.

Comment: @Velthune If `byte` is defined as `unsigned char`, and you're working on a typical machine with 8 bit chars, then there's no way that your expression can have a value of `0xfffffff1`; that value simply isn't representable in an `unsigned char`.

Comment: ok, I'm forgetting an "unsigned" in a part of code, my fault!